# How to change title attribute on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

### What is my problem (What am I trying to achieve)?

- So I have `<li>` with title attribute which is visible when that `<li>` element is hovered and I want to change the text of the title attribute, currently it is set to "Details" like this `<li title="Details">`.

### What Have I tried?

- I have had function in functions.php, which uses gettext and it works usually on every element; Therefore I tried to do it also here, but it's unsucessfull.

```
add_filter('gettext',function($strings) 
{
    $text = array(
        'Details' => 'Pregledaj',
        'Ship to'   => 'Dostavite na',
    );
    $strings = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $strings );
    return $strings;
}, 20 );
```

Comment: Hello smack857, first of all, could you please rephrase your question in order to make it more clear about what you are trying to achieve? Secondary, Have you tried javascript? ( Or to modify the button source itself? ).

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis Hm, I think it's actually clear what I want to achieve, like stated I want to change text of `title` attribute on `<li>` element from "Details" to "Pregledajte".  Well, it's not really an option to go into theme files and change it within that file, because if new update of theme is released and I update it, it would get reseted, so that option isn't really good option. I am trying JS right now, tho... Good idea

Comment: Are you familiar with child themes? If not make sure to read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) to get extra enlightened.